# "AND" with data and countable thing

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I have the following sentence.

> The system must be scalable so it will remain effective when there is a significant increase in data and the number of users.

I don't know if it is grammatically correct; I used *and* between *data* which is uncountable,  and "the number of users" which is countable.

Am I right? Is there any better situation that sentence will be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using *and* between an uncountable noun and a countable noun.

> I need water and four eggs.

*And* just means the increase was noted for the data, and it was also noted for the number of users.

Comment: so my sentence is right?

Comment: Yes, it is. I would rather write "there is a significant increase in data and number of users"; that is my style, though.